# Anyone getting errors on attempting to save Edits to posts?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing

Lately I've been experiencing errors on attempting to save question edits. I will edit the question, say over a minute or two (edit title, body, retag perhaps), hit the Save Edits button, and I will either get an error:

[image]

or I will get nothing - as in it will attempt to save, but not and I get no error, and I am still on the edit page with my edits just sitting there. I can reload the page, or even come back to it later in the day, and I usually get the same thing when trying to edit again and just end up not being able to edit the post at all. Anyone else experiencing anything like this?

Comment: You're using Firefox 9.0.1 and Windows 7?  And the last question you tried editing was [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/bounding-box-for-app-engine)?  What did you try to edit on that question?

Comment: @JarrodDixon - Correct - FF 9.0.1 and Win7. Yes, that is the [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/bounding-box-for-app-engine), I attempted to edit the title and the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had some intermittent CDN issues with some of the CDN nodes, so you were getting out of data JavaScript files for the website. This should be resolved now; sorry about that.